# Basis for an infinite dimensional vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is there any good paper that focus on the topic of basis for infinite dimensional vector space that I can read/ study. I found some papers that mention about this topic online, but they are very brief and not too thorough.

Thank you for any input!

Comment: What is your background? Have you had a course in real analysis/Banach spaces/Hilbertspaces?

Comment: @IBWiglin I have one course in real analysis and one in linear algebra and matrix theory

Comment: Was this a graduate level course in real analysis?

Comment: @IBWiglin: I think it is, but I'm in it as an undergraduate; this is not required in the course, though. It is just something my professor mentioned in class that I want to look into.